# Consulta ajax con parametros distintos no me actualiza la respuesta

Tags: php, html, ajax, datatables, parametros

Les hago una consulta ya que tengo un problema y no puedo encontrar la solucióon. Tengo un datatable cargado con datos de clientes desde una BD y en cada renglón un par de botones. Uno de ellos llama a un modal, pasáandole el ID del registro, y muestra otro datatable con el detalle de comprobantes del cliente. Uso php y los datatables los lleno con ajax. El tema esta en que observo que cada vez que llamo al modal pasa el ID correspondiente al renglon pero el ajax me devuelve siempre el mismo resultado. Siempre el resultado del primer id que envío. No tengo ningún error. Y en el log del apache tampoco... solo veo en el log del mysql que pasa el mismo id en todas las consultas siendo que yo veo que le estoy pasando otro distinto. He buscado en google y no he podido dar con la solución. Gracias.

Este es el código:

```
// js que se ejecuta al presional el boton.
$(document).on("click", ".btnVerCuenta", function(){
  var datos = { "idDeudor": $(this).attr("idUsuario") };
  alert(JSON.stringify(datos));
  $('.tablaModal').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "ajax/modal.ajax.php",
      "data": datos,
      "type": "POST",
      "cache": false
    },
    "deferRender": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true,
    "language": {
      "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
      "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
      "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
      "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
      "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
      "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
      "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
      "sInfoPostFix":    "",
      "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
      "sUrl":            "",
      "sInfoThousands":  ",",
      "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Primero",
        "sLast":     "Último",
        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
      },
      "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
      }
    }
  });
});


// Este es el ajax
<?php

require_once "../controladores/comprobantes.ctr.php";
require_once "../modelos/comprobantes.mdl.php";


class DetalleDeuda{

  public $deudor;
    public function mostrarTablaDeuda(){
        $campo = "id_usuario";
    $valor = $this -> deudor;
    $detalle = ControladorComprobantes::VerComprobantesDetalles($campo, $valor);
        if(count($detalle) == 0){
            echo '{"data": []}';
        return;
        }
        $datosJson = '{
          "data": [';
          for($i = 0; $i < count($detalle); $i++){
            $datosJson .='[
              "'.$detalle[$i]["cbnte_nro"].'",
              "'.$detalle[$i]["cbnte_fecha"].'",
                    "'.$detalle[$i]["cbnte_importe"].'",
                    "'.$detalle[$i]["cbnte_estado"].'"
            ],';
          }
          $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);
      $datosJson .=   ']
        }';
        echo $datosJson;
     }
}



if(isset($_POST["idDeudor"])){
  $activarTabla = new DetalleDeuda();
    $activarTabla -> deudor = $_POST["idDeudor"];
    $activarTabla -> mostrarTablaDeuda();
}

// el codigo html de los botones
<td>
                          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnVerCuenta" idUsuario="'.$value["id"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detalleUsuario"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></button>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></button>
                          <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></button>
                        </td>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Por favor edita la pregunta para complementar, incluyendo un ejemplo de al menos dos filas de la tabla con su botón, para ver cómo estás tomando el valor y saber si el error está ahí o en otra parte.

Comment: Ahi pegue la porcion del codigo en donde muestra las lineas en el datatables. Como se ve en js inclui un alert para ver si estaba pasando bien idDeudor, y si.. me muestra el valor que llega. Gracias.